# Set class for wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress, navigation, html-lists

How to convert this :

```
<ul class="ulStyle">
<li class="liStyle">
<div class="first">
<div class="second">
menu1
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

to wp_nav_menu

Too many div and class inside there, anyone can help me solve this problem?Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the `nth-child()` selector in css

see the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qilKp)

use this css:

```
.wp_nav_menu div:nth-child(1) {

  background: blue;

}

.wp_nav_menu div:nth-child(2) {

  background: red;

}
```

with the following markup:

```
<ul class="wp_nav_menu">
  <li>
    <div>
      Foo
    </div>
    <div>
      Bar
    </div>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are using a custom theme that have probably a Walker. In WordPress you can use a Walker to modify the HTML rendered by wp_nav_menu.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class

First, see if there is one, normally in theme/functions.php

Comment: The default walker already has options to change the encapsulation of your menu and menu items. Custom walkers can do much more, but that might be a bit too much for this particular issue.

Comment: Looks like he already have a walker since the default rendered HTML has only ul, li and a. He can start by removing it maybe!

Answer (score 0):

Before starting with custom walkers, use the options `before`, `after`, `link_before`, `link_after` and `items_wrap`. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

It will allow you to change the encapsulation of your menu items.